# conditional tax in financial payment page for membership

Tags: taxes, financial-accounts

I am trying to setup conditional tax based on province for one membership in payment page. is there any reference I can use? is this hook needed and also custom code?

I am using drupal 7 with civi crm 4.7.1 version

some references would be great.

thank you

Answer (score 1):

The easy - non-code - way to handle this is to create a Drupal node (page) with a select Province - and then based on Province selected popup a button with a link to a Contribution page that is configured with a Priceset that sells that Membership at that Province's General Sales Tax.

Edit: this is the only sustainable way to do this right now (see comment below).

Answer (score -1):

One way of Doing this:
First of all you need to create priceset for the membership 
and you need to create an Extension for handling this calculation and you can use hook_civicrm_buildAmount() and please put all you code in the extension

Please refer to the below link for hooks

https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Hook+Reference

Comment: I am trying to get province working with tax for membership, is there any extension for that, or this is a pretty hard hook for it?

Comment: I did look at this w/ Mathieu Lufty recently and yes it’s easy to add a buildAmount hook to override the default tax rate - however - you can’t edit (which includes emailing a receipt; adding a note) such Contributions as on Save sales tax gets recalculated on every single save. And you end up with a Tax refund in your financial items.